# MongoDB lack of precision incrementing floats

Tags: python, mongodb, floating-accuracy

I have a problem, because MongoDB doesn't seem to maintain precision when incrementing floats.  For example, the following should yield `2.0`:

```
from decimal import Decimal  # For Python precision
for i in range(40):
    db.test.update({}, {'$inc': {'count': float(Decimal(1) / 20)}}, upsert=True)
print db.test.find_one()['count']
```

Output:

```
2.000000000000001
```

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Probably by fixing the precision in your client code. It is afterall the part that is providing the value in the first place. So understand that **you** are causing the problem and not the interface. "Keyboard - Chair" interface problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't—at least not directly. MongoDB stores floating-point numbers as double-precision [IEEE floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), and those rounding errors are inherent to the format.

I'm noticing you're using Decimals in your code—they're converted to Python floats (which are doubles) before being sent to the DB. If you want to keep your true decimal precision, you'll have to store your numbers as stringified Decimals, which means you'll also have to give up MongoDB's number-handling facilities such as `$inc`.

It is, sadly, a tradeoff you'll be confronted to in most databases and programming languages: IEEE floating-point numbers is the format CPUs natively deal with, and any attempts to stray away from them (to use arbitrary-precision decimals like `decimal.Decimal`) come with a big performance and usability penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and below is the solution.

The output you get is a common issue in programming due to the way floating-point numbers are represented and stored in computers.

The solution is simple - you just have to round the whole result.

My code is a javascript but you can easily convert it to python.

```js
let newVal = 2

await Statistics.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") }, [
    {
        $set: {
            totalFieldArea: {
                $round: [
                    { $add: ["$totalFieldArea", newVal] },
                    2, // Round to 2 decimal places
                ],
            },
        },
    },
]);
```